# Voltage-divider bias common emitter calculations are yielding unexpected results

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, common-emitter, negative-feedback

I performed an analysis on this voltage-divider-feedback common emitter.  My result in simulation is relatively close, but doesn't quite check out.  Where did I go wrong?  I'm new to this and expecting it's either something I've missed in my learning or some simple mistake I made and didn't notice.

[image]

The circuit has a quiescent current of 3.4 mA, and the collector is nicely centered at 6V.  \$\beta = 250\$.  For the AC analysis, I redrew the circuit using the hybrid-pi model.  I assumed \$C_C\$ is open to AC at the frequency of interest:

[image]

I started by finding \$g_m=\frac{I_C}{V_T}=\frac{3.4mA}{25mV}=0.136\$ and \$r_\pi=\frac{\beta}{g_m}=\frac{250}{0.136}=1838\Omega\$

Next I used nodal analysis of the output node to determine \$A_V\$.
$$ i_{in}+i_c+i_f=0$$
$$ \frac{v_{out}}{R_C} + g_mv_{be}+\bigl(\frac{v_{out}}{R_F} -\frac{v_{in}}{R_F}\bigr) = 0 $$
$$ v_{out}\bigl(\frac{1}{R_C} + \frac{1}{R_F}\bigr)=v_{in}\bigl(\frac{1}{R_F} - g_m)$$
$$ {v_{out}\over R_C||R_F} = -v_{in}\bigl(g_m-\frac{1}{R_F}\bigr)$$
$$A_v = {v_{out}\over v_{in}} = -\bigl(g_m-\frac{1}{R_F}\bigr)\bigl(R_C||R_F\bigr)$$
$$ A_v = -\bigl(0.136-\frac{1}{390k}\bigr)\bigl(1760||390k\bigr)$$
$$ A_v = -238$$

Then I found \$R_{in}\$ by comparing expressions for input voltage and current:

$$ R_{in} = {v_{in}\over i_{in}} = {v_{in}\over i_b-i_f} $$
$$ R_{in} = {v_{in}\over{\frac{v_{in}}{r_\pi}}- {\frac{v_{in}-v_{out}}{R_F}}}$$
$$ R_{in} = {v_{in}\over{\frac{v_{in}}{r_\pi}}+ {\frac{v_{in}-A_vv_{in}}{R_F}}}$$
$$ R_{in} = {1\over{\frac{1}{r_\pi}}+ {\frac{1-A_v}{R_F}}}$$
$$ R_{in} = r_\pi||{\frac{R_F}{1-A_v}} $$
$$ R_{in} = 1838||{\frac{390k}{1-(-238)}} $$
$$ R_{in} = 864\Omega$$

\$R_{out}\$ was simpler to see by inspection, and is simply \$R_F||R_C = 1752\Omega\$

The problem is, when I simulate the circuit it does not yield the expected values.  I set \$v_{in}=0.02V\$ peak-to-peak at \$1kHz\$.  Given my values for gain, I should expect an output voltage of \$4.7v\$ but I get \$4.0v\$.  I tried a range of voltages for input, and anything up to around \$40mV\$ gives a consistent gain of 200, instead of the expected 238.  Similarly, my current \$i_{in}\$ should be \$v_{in}/R_{in}=0.02V/864\Omega=23\mu A\$.  When I simulate this, the input current is approx. \$10\mu A\$.  Output resistance isn't correct either.  Expecting an output resistance of \$1752\Omega\$, I added an \$R_L=1752\Omega\$ to the circuit expecting my output voltage drop to 50%.
The circuit I analyzed behaves as if it is:
$$ A_v=-200 $$
$$ R_{in} = 2066\Omega $$
$$ R_{out} = 3280\Omega $$

**What is/are the error(s) in my equations that are causing my gain, input resistance, and output resistance to be so different from the simulation?**

If you'd like to see the simulation it can be found here:
https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6222614442541056

Comment: Looks like your link at the bottom of your post must be "private." I cannot access it.

Comment: Edit your link bro. Its private it says

Comment: Check your nodal equation there are two nodes

Comment: Your hand calculations will never be as exact as a simulation tool so why you expect exactness is more relevant for you to concentrate on.

Comment: Link is fixed now.

Comment: So is there any error leading to my answers, or are they correct, but incomplete?  Do I need to do analysis from the other node also?  Is a different model more likely to yield correct answers?

Comment: Notice that the transistor use has by default a 1-ohm resistor build into the emitter. Therefore the voltage gain will drop to \$ \Large A_V = \frac{R_C||R_F}{\frac{1}{g_m} + RE} - \frac{R_C}{R_F + R_C} \approx 202\$   And this will slightly increase the Rin as well.

Comment: And from whats I see Rin in your simulation you have set Vin to 10mV thus Rin =1k

Comment: @G36 thank you for finding that built-in resistance in the simulation model!  That explains why I was seeing 200 for gain, which was bugging me. It's actually a 20mV input though, I'm comparing peak-peak input and output.

Comment: so why did you divide by 10uA instead of 20uA?